# bash: Can't properly output 7 digit long integer

Tags: bash, shell

If I try to print integers that are 6 or less digits long everything works perfect:

Example

```
for i in $(seq 123450 123451); do printf "%7.0f\n" $i; done
```

> 123450
>
> 123451

However, when integers are 7 or more digits long the last digit of the number is being output as '0':

Example

```
for i in $(seq 1234560 1234561); do printf "%7.0f\n" $i; done
```

> 1234560
>
> 1234560

Question: what problem do I encounter and what should I do to be able to use "long" integers?

Comment: Why are you printing integers with a floating point format?

Comment: Works for me in bash 3.2.48 (Mac OS X) and bash 4.

Comment: @Carl Norum Thank you for the comment! When I try echo $i, I get 1.23456e+06
1.23456e+06

Comment: @chepner Ok, thanks! I tried on the other computer and everything worked fine - so, it is a bash version problem! Problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `seq` prints its output in %g format:

```
$ seq 1234560 1234561
1.23456e+06
1.23456e+06
```

so use `seq -f "%7.0f"` instead:

```
$ seq -f "%7.0f" 1234560 1234561
1234560
1234561
```

or just `seq -f "%.0f"`:

```
$ seq -f "%.0f" 1234560 1234561
1234560
1234561
```

Comment: Thank you! "for i in $(seq -f "%7.0f" 123450 123451); do printf "%s\n" $i; done" worked!

Answer (score 1):

For the shell, everything is a string and floating point conversions and computations are best avoided and left to `bc`(1). This should work:

```
 for i in $(seq 123450 123451); do printf "%s\n" $i; done
```